# LeakCanary received Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I am trying to fix the memory leak using the LeakCanary and honestly, I can't understand the stack trace that was showing me. I am using a firebase paging option and stop the listening on the `onDestroy` method. I also did not pass any activity or context to the adapter so I am sure that there is no problem in that. Below are the logs from the LeakCanary.

```
    HEAP ANALYSIS RESULT
    ====================================
    1 APPLICATION LEAKS
    
    References underlined with "~~~" are likely causes.
    Learn more at https://squ.re/leaks.
    
    31417285 bytes retained by leaking objects
    Signature: 31c372d2f2d3d219e828763d8f853ceca5851b
    ┬───
    │ GC Root: System class
    │
    ├─ leakcanary.internal.InternalLeakCanary class
    │    Leaking: NO (HomeBuyersActivity↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
    │    ↓ static InternalLeakCanary.resumedActivity
    ├─ com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity.HomeBuyersActivity instance
    │    Leaking: NO (Activity#mDestroyed is false)
    │    ↓ HomeBuyersActivity.mLifecycleRegistry
    │                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ LifecycleRegistry.mObserverMap
    │                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ├─ androidx.arch.core.internal.FastSafeIterableMap instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ FastSafeIterableMap.mEnd
    │                          ~~~~
    ├─ androidx.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$Entry instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ SafeIterableMap$Entry.mKey
    │                            ~~~~
    ├─ com.dreamakers.coonna.Adapter.DiscoverStoreAdapter instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    ↓ DiscoverStoreAdapter.mParser
    │                           ~~~~~~~
    ├─ com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity.HomeFragment$11 instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Anonymous class implementing com.firebase.ui.firestore.SnapshotParser
    │    ↓ HomeFragment$11.this$0
    │                      ~~~~~~
    ╰→ com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity.HomeFragment instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.dreamakers.coonna.Activity.HomeFragment received Fragment#onDestroy() callback and Fragment#mFragmentManager is null)
    ​     key = 6e0451ae-0c0b-4de8-8993-011515e95a80
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 6238
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 1238
    ====================================
    0 LIBRARY LEAKS
    
    A Library Leak is a leak caused by a known bug in 3rd party code that you do not have control over.
    See https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals-how-leakcanary-works/#4-categorizing-leaks
    ====================================
    METADATA
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HomeFragment was destroyed and should be garbage collected, but it cannot be garbage collected because DiscoverStoreAdapter is registered as a lifecycle listener on HomeBuyersActivity and DiscoverStoreAdapter has a mParser field which is an anonymous class implementing SnapshotParser in HomeFragment.

It's hard to say without the code, but DiscoverStoreAdapter.mParser should probably be set to null when the fragment is destroyed.

Comment: hi i am getting same issue, ref this link : (leakcanary screenshot & my code) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514151/whats-the-best-practice-to-prevent-memory-leaks-using-datastore/66515644#66515644