# What's the best practice to prevent memory leaks using Datastore?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-datastore

I try to store & get data using a datastore-preference alpha07, everything working fine, I got some memory leak issue in the datastore

What's the best practice to prevent memory leaks using Datastore?

here is my sample code:

```
// Preferences DataStore
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0-alpha07"
// Leakcanary find memory leak
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.6'
```

UserManager.kt

```
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map

class UserManager(val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>) {

    //Create some keys
    companion object {
        val USER_AGE_KEY = intPreferencesKey("USER_AGE")
        val USER_FIRST_NAME_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("USER_FIRST_NAME")
        val USER_LAST_NAME_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("USER_LAST_NAME")
        val USER_GENDER_KEY = booleanPreferencesKey("USER_GENDER")
    }

    //Store user data
    suspend fun storeUser(age: Int, fname: String, lname: String, isMale: Boolean) {
        dataStore.edit {
            it[USER_AGE_KEY] = age
            it[USER_FIRST_NAME_KEY] = fname
            it[USER_LAST_NAME_KEY] = lname
            it[USER_GENDER_KEY] = isMale

        }
    }

    //Create an age flow
    val userAgeFlow: Flow<Int?> = dataStore.data.map {
        it[USER_AGE_KEY]
    }

    //Create a fname flow
    val userFirstNameFlow: Flow<String?> = dataStore.data.map {
        it[USER_FIRST_NAME_KEY]
    }

    //Create a lname flow
    val userLastNameFlow: Flow<String?> = dataStore.data.map {
        it[USER_LAST_NAME_KEY]
    }

    //Create a gender flow
    val userGenderFlow: Flow<Boolean?> = dataStore.data.map {
        it[USER_GENDER_KEY]
    }

}
```

User.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore

// At the top level of your kotlin file:
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "user_prefs")
```

SignInFragment.kt

```
 //Get reference to our userManager class
               var userManager = UserManager(requireContext().dataStore)
        
                //Stores the values
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    userManager.storeUser(1, "android", "studio", true)
                }
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
var userManager = UserManager(requireContext().dataStore)
       userManager.userAgeFlow.asLiveData().observe(requireActivity(), {
            if (it != null) {
                age = it
                //tv_age.text = it.toString()
            }
        })
```

Memory leak issue:
[image]

[image]

**Below solution not working**
I tried, still I am getting leaks even tried this solution,
Observer should be bind with component's lifecycle in this case Fragment's lifecycle . Use viewLifeCycleOwner instead to bind the observer.

HomeFragment.kt

```
 var userManager = UserManager(viewLifecycleOwner.dataStore)
           userManager.userAgeFlow.asLiveData().observe(viewLifeCycleOwner, {
                if (it != null) {
                    // age = it
                    // tv_age.text = it.toString()
                }
            })
```

Ref screenshot (again replicated)
[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Suggested fix

Using your `Activity's` or `Fragment's` context is indeed fishy, and actually there's no need to do so. Instead, if you pass a global context of your application (`applicationContext`), then `DataStore` won't leak any UI contexts and will process your `Preferences` requests independently from the lifecycle of the UI component on which they start.

In your `Fragments`, write the following:

```
...
var userManager = UserManager(requireContext().applicationContext.dataStore) 
...
```

In your `MainActivity`, it will be even simpler:

```
...
var userManager = UserManager(applicationContext.dataStore) 
...
```

## Result

That's how many leaks have been detected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding same as answer Since the problem is resolved.

The reason `Observer` is causing memory leak is because its bind to lifecycle of `Activity` with use of `requireActivity()` .

`Observer` should be bind with component's lifecycle in this case Fragment's lifecycle .  Use `viewLifeCycleOwner` instead to bind the observer.

Comment: still, I am getting leaks (leak canary), screenshot updated in question. can u help me to fix it, (issue type: replicated)

Comment: sometimes the observer needs to be bound to the activity because it's a shared observer and that's the only way I found to communicate between fragment and activity for example.